# Select script to include count of another table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to figure out how to write a script to select certain records/fields from one table, then join it to another table and include a column for a corresponding count. For example, this is what I have now:

```
select ID, Val from OriginalTable where Something = 1
```

Now I have another table which has records linking to this original table, where the a column `OriginalID` matches the `ID` of the `OriginalTable`. One example would be:

```
select * from OtherTable where OriginalID = 3
```

...where 3 = the `ID` of the `OriginalTable`.

What I'd like to do is add a column to the first statement which shows a count of the other table as shown in the second query. For example, this might be a result set:

```
ID    Val    Count
1     abc    15
2     def    23
3     ghi    42
4     jkl    19
```

How do I write this query to include this count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this, but you could either use a `Group By`

```
select ID, Val, [Count] = count(1)
from OriginalTable be
left join OtherTable ot on be.OriginalID = ot.OriginalID
where Something = 1
group by ID,Val
```

or you could use `OVER` and `Partition By`:

```
select ID, Val, [Count] = count(1) OVER(PARTITION BY ID,Val)
from OriginalTable be
left join OtherTable ot on be.OriginalID = ot.OriginalID
where Something = 1
```

Personally I like the `OVER` method. There's information on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx).

Comment: In your answer what does the 1 in `count(1)` represent? 

I'm trying to use your example as I think its what I need, but I am getting many results(duplicate rows) returned for each row now with the `OVER` method

but in my query instead of 1 I have the column I want it to count

Comment: Count(1) or Count(*) are interchangeable, but different from Count(col) which will not include nulls in the column. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1. There may once have been a time when they were different (early oracle or sql server)

Answer (score 2):

A subquery should handle that for you:

```
SELECT 
  ID, Val, Cnt
FROM OriginalTable
JOIN (
  SELECT 
    OriginalID, COUNT(*) AS Cnt
  FROM OtherTable
  GROUP BY OriginalID
  ) AS Sub ON ID=OriginalID
```

Comment: This ended up being the example that worked best for me, thanks.
Using SQL Report Builder seemed to not like the `Over Partitioned By` method above

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH ot(ID, c) AS 
(
  SELECT OriginalID, COUNT(*)
   FROM dbo.OtherTable
   GROUP BY OriginalID
)
SELECT t.ID, t.Val, [Count] = COALESCE(ot.c, 0)
  FROM dbo.OriginalTable AS t
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ot
  ON t.ID = ot.ID
  WHERE t.Something = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT be.ID, be.Val, Count(*) AS [Count]
FROM OriginalTable be
LEFT OUTER JOIN OtherTable ot ON be.ID = ot.OriginalID
WHERE be.Something = 1
GROUP BY be.ID, be.Val
```

Comment: Awkward how `be` actually perfectly matches what I intended to convert it to in the first place :D

Comment: Ah, oops, I forgot to remove that actually, I tried to re-write it excluding business specific stuff, anyway, that works for me, now which answer to accept?